# How can I pass $scope to a a resolve promise function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['firebase'])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

$routeProvider

 .when('/test', {
    templateUrl: '/views/test.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    resolve:
    {
        loaddata: testCtrl.loaddata
    }
      });
    }]);

var testCtrl = testApp.controller('TestCtrl',['$scope', function  ($scope) {

}]);

testCtrl.loaddata = function($scope) {



    return promise;

}
```

Problem is that I can't inject $scope here:
testCtrl.loaddata = function($scope) {

How can I get $scope in a resolve function?

Comment: why do u want $scope in resolve ??

Comment: var promise = angularFire('https://test.firebaseio.com/items', $scope, 'items', []);

It has $scope to pass as parameter.

Comment: $rootScope works here, but I don't want to use global scope